# Android, flutter errror : Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I got an error when I installed Google-play Services tool, What is the problem? I googled and searched for a long time, but I couldn't know what is the problem.

Below is the error message

> use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask
>   is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>   C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\18d5967141a97e1c47095b347e0363df\res\layout-v21\notification_template_custom_big.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\18d5967141a97e1c47095b347e0363df\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-26.1.0.aar\f6856f0a6bf11837b0484543a04fb51a\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\18d5967141a97e1c47095b347e0363df\res\drawable-v21\notification_action_background.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\18d5967141a97e1c47095b347e0363df\res\drawable\notification_bg.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\googleg_disabled_color_18.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\18d5967141a97e1c47095b347e0363df\res\layout-v21\notification_template_icon_group.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\18d5967141a97e1c47095b347e0363df\res\drawable\notification_tile_bg.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-26.1.0.aar\f6856f0a6bf11837b0484543a04fb51a\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> C:\Users\?????.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\93c2774cf3ab39eadc13fc662c2d7b36\res\color\common_google_signin_btn_tint.xml:
>   error: file not found.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   >     details
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 13s Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1

Answer (score 0):

The issue was likely caused by the outdated `google-services` version configured in the Android build. What you can do here is update the Firebase plugins that you're using and run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to update the installed plugins and index. If that didn't solve the issue, you can delete the `/android` build folder and generate a new one by running `flutter create --platforms=android` in the Terminal.